# preg_match_all specific directory/path using php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am am trying to get all links from a page but i would like to match specific directory/path. i am currently using the code below:

```
preg_match_all("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/is", $sPageContent, $aResults);
```

the above code gets all the link of the page but i need s solution that would get links from specific directory, I like to match directories/paths with /music/music/.

For example, I have these links:

```
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/397/adoramus-te/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/3113/obsesi/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2707/the-piano/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2677/irreemplazable/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/25981/lo/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/top/1243/core/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/top/12/late/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/top/13/new/
```

From the links above, I want to get all links that looks like these:

```
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/397/adoramus-te/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/3113/obsesi/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2707/the-piano/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2677/irreemplazable/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/25981/lo/
```

but ignore every other links

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get the href's from an anchor. You could use for example domdocument instead to find all the anchors, get the href and the match `https?://[^/]*/music/music/\S+`

Comment: thanks but cos exactly can i use your code in this case, where do i put it here: preg_match_all("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/is", $sPageContent, $aResults);

Comment: If you replace your preg_match_all line with `preg_match_all('/(?<=a href=")(.*)music\/music(.*)(?=")/', $sPageContent, $aResults);` it should match the pattern that you're looking for

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1):

You might use for example [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the data, and then get all the anchors from it.

Then use a pattern to match `/music/music/` from the first forward slash after https://

```
^https?://[^/]+/music/music/\S+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional `s`
- `[^/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `/music/music/` Match literally
- `\S+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKaHzM/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/o8sPe)

**Example code**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $url = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    if (preg_match("~^https?://[^/]+/music/music/\S+$~", $url)) {
        echo $url . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/397/adoramus-te/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/3113/obsesi/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2707/the-piano/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/2677/irreemplazable/
https://www.example.co.uk/music/music/25981/lo/
```